# Streaming a file from remote S3 to react client through rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, file, backend

The app already does this using Zipline and allowing to stream one zip file with all the files selected. But what I want to accomplish is that if only one file is being sent achieve the same behavior but instead of sending a compressed zip file sending the file as it is in S3 (with its respective extension such as docx, jpeg, xlsx, etc). So this is what I have so far.

controller

```
def to_zip_or_single
    if params[:attachments].present?
      fileNames = {}
      files = Attachment.where(id: params[:attachments]
        .split(','))
                        .map do |attachment|
        file = attachment.is_image? ? AbstractFileStruct.new(attachment.upload_annotated) : attachment.upload
        if !fileNames[attachment.name]
          fileNames[attachment.name] = 0
        else
          fileNames[attachment.name] += 1
        end
        attachmentName = File.basename(attachment.name, File.extname(attachment.name))
        attachmentName = if fileNames[attachment.name] > 0
                           attachmentName + " (#{fileNames[attachment.name]})" + File.extname(attachment.name)
                         else
                           attachmentName + File.extname(attachment.name)
                         end
        [file, attachmentName]
      end
    end

    filename = params[:filename].present? ? params[:filename] : 'attachments.zip'

    if files.one?

      headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + files[0][1] + '"'
      headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
      response.headers['Last-Modified'] = Time.now.httpdate
      response.cache_control[:public] ||= false
      response.sending_file = true


      file = normalize(files[0][0])

      the_remote_uri = URI(file[:url])

      Net::HTTP.get_response(the_remote_uri) do |response|
        # DO SOMETHING WITH THE RESPONSE
      end

    elsif files
      zipline(files, filename)
    end

  end

def normalize(file)
    file = file.file if defined?(CarrierWave::Uploader::Base) && file.is_a?(CarrierWave::Uploader::Base)

    if defined?(Paperclip) && file.is_a?(Paperclip::Attachment)
      if file.options[:storage] == :filesystem
        { file: File.open(file.path) }
      else
        { url: file.expiring_url }
      end
    elsif defined?(CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File) && file.is_a?(CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File)
      { url: file.url }
    elsif defined?(CarrierWave::SanitizedFile) && file.is_a?(CarrierWave::SanitizedFile)
      { file: File.open(file.path) }
    elsif is_io?(file)
      { file: file }
    elsif defined?(ActiveStorage::Blob) && file.is_a?(ActiveStorage::Blob)
      { blob: file }
    elsif is_active_storage_attachment?(file) || is_active_storage_one?(file)
      { blob: file.blob }
    elsif file.respond_to? :url
      { url: file.url }
    elsif file.respond_to? :path
      { file: File.open(file.path) }
    elsif file.respond_to? :file
      { file: File.open(file.file) }
    elsif is_url?(file)
      { url: file }
    else
      raise(ArgumentError, 'Bad File/Stream')
    end
  end
```

I am a complete noobie to Rails and ruby. What I ultimately want is to be able to download the file from a react client using something like this

```
axios({
        url: path,
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'blob',
      }).then( async (response) => {
        const fileHandle = await window.showSaveFilePicker({suggestedName: "download", types: [{accept: {"application/octet-stream":[".docx"]}}]});
        const writable = await fileHandle.createWritable();
        await writable.write( response.data );
        await writable.close();
      })
```

I am also not familiarized on how to work with files that good. I understand I have to use something like a writter and stream the file by chunks. I have tried some code such as

```
open 'large_file', 'w' do |io|
          response.read_body do |chunk|
            io.write chunk
          end
        end
```

and

```
response.read_body do |chunk|
              chunk
            end
```

But none of those have worked. If anyone could point me in the right direction or give me some ideas of what could I try in this scenario I would appreciate a lot

**UPDATE**

I have tried the following approach

```
Net::HTTP.get_response(the_remote_uri) do |response|
        reader.close

        open 'large_file', 'w' do |_io|
          response.read_body do |chunk|
            toWrite = chunk.force_encoding('UTF-8')
            writer.write(toWrite)
          end
        end
      end
```

But it gives me this error

```
<Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as this worked for now, I dont think I am streaming the response
but still it does work, hopefully it will work with large files as well

```
Net::HTTP.get_response(the_remote_uri) do |resp|
  self.response_body = resp.read_body
end
```